# Multi-tenancy query execution speed: shared-schema with partitioning vs. seperate-schema

Tags: azure-sql-database, saas

I've been reading through the excellent [Developing Multi-tenant Applications for the Cloud, 3rd Edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534476.aspx) and am trying to understand how partitioning impacts on query performance in Windows Azure SQL Database.

If you use the shared schema approach and put all tenants records in a single table and separate their data using partitions, is that always going to be slower than a separate schema approach due to the larger number of records in the table, or does the partitioning effectively make each partition act like its own table?

(I appreciate query execution speed is only one of many factors to consider when choosing a multi tenancy strategy, we're not basing our decisions on performance alone.)

Answer (score 1):

The approach that uses different schemas for different tenants has its problems, too. For instance, it is very easy to bloat the plan cache with this approach since each tenant gets its own set of query plans. You may end up with more recompiles (and lower performance) with this approach because of that.

I would recommend to take a look at an approach where you place each tenant in its own database. That provides for great isolation and, in combination with Elastic Database Pools in Azure SQL DB, it actually becomes quite affordable. A good entry point into the documentation is this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction/.